# Numbering for mobile verification call to China in Chinese

Tags: translation, pronunciation, number

I am making a chat application , so for number verification I need to make calls (**your verification code is 1234**) on the number.
I want to know if I called to China in Chinese then how the numbers are pronounced. **Is it the same one two three?** and then the remaining sentence in chinese?

This is the xml that is used for calling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
     <Say voice="alice" language="zh-CN" loop="2">您的新密码是 1 2 3 4</Say>
</Response>
```

If this complete sentence is spoken in Chinese, other than the numbers, is it the correct way to call?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, could you be more specific?

Comment: @ChineseHulu.com i updated my question

Comment: numbers automatically pronounced in chinese

Comment: I've suggested an edit for grammar (and tagging), but there were some bits I couldn't really understand some of it. If I've changed the meaning of something, feel free to revert changes.

Answer (score 3):

The translation for "your verification code is 1234" in Chinese should be

"您的认证码是 一 二 三 四" or "您的认证码是 1 2 3 4" in your code.

Note：

“1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10”

are pronounced as "yi1 er4 san1 si4 wu3 liu4 qi1 ba1 jiu3 shi2" in Chinese.

are written as "一 二 三 四 五 六 七 八 九 十" in Chinese.

Comment: thanks can you update the answer with 0 to 10 if possible

Comment: and what is for zero?

Comment: @GovindSingh 零 ling2

Comment: As a side note, 1 in numbers are often read as 幺(yao1). Like in English, 0 can be read as zero or oh.

Comment: never heard a computer generated voice to pronounce 1 as yao1 though.